# check A LOT of folders with Powershell

Tags: memory, powershell, foreach, internal, subdirectory

my problem is with Powershell.
I have a very big Folder. Insider are about 1 600 000 Subfolders. 
My task is to erase all empty folders or files beneath them which are older than 6 months.
I wrote a loop with foreach but it takes ages before powershell starts with it ->

...

```
foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -recurse -force | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $date })
{
# here comes a script which will erase the file when its older than 6 months
# here comes a script which will erase the folder if it's a folder AND does not have child items of its own
```

...

The Problem: my internal memory gets full(4GB) and i cant properly work anymore.
My guess: powershell loads all 1 600 000 folders, and only after that it begins to filter them.

Is there a possibility to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, all 1.6M folders, or at least references to them, are being loaded at once. Best practice is to filter left & format right; IOW, remove those folders before you hit `Where-Object` if at all possible (unfortunately, `gci` doesn't support a date filter AFAICT). Also, if you keep things in the pipeline, you'll use less memory.

The following will restrict `$items` to only those folders which match your criteria, then perform your loop over those objects.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -path $rootpath -recurse -force | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt $date }
foreach ($item in $items) {
# here comes a script which will erase the file when its older than 6 months
# here comes a script which will erase the folder if it's a folder AND does not have child items of its own
}
```

Or streamlining further:

```
function runScripts {
    # here comes a script which will erase the file when its older than 6 months. Pass $input into that script. $input will be a folder.
    # here comes a script which will erase the folder if it's a folder AND does not have child items of its own Pass $input into that script. $input will be a folder.
}
Get-ChildItem -path $rootpath -recurse -force | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt $date }|runScripts
```

In this last case, you're using `runScripts` as a function which uses the pipelined object as a parameter which can be operated on (`$input`), so you can send everything through the pipeline instead of using those intermediate objects (which will consume more memory).

Comment: Thanks i just tested it in a smaller enviroment. (106 000 folders)
It took about 73s with my original skript.
With you modifikations (streamlining) it just took me 51s.
Thanks!